# accessing option value from form control to use in component model

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-ngmodel

I am trying to get the value of an option selection back into my component class for some logic later on. However, it returns as undefined, even if I have hardcoded the value of `[value]="unit"` in my view as the options, when I pass it through, `onModelChange(unit)` it comes as undefined.
Basically I need to give a value to my form-group instance but also get the value of that field to do some logic for another field.

view
     New Job Entry

```
<div  class="card container form-container">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <form (ngSubmit)="createJobEntry(job_entry)" 
        #jobEntryForm="ngForm">

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="dropdown" dropdown>
      <label class="label-text" for="material" >Material</label>
        <select class="form-control"
                  (ngModelChange)="onMaterialChange($event)"
                  required
                  id="material"
                  name="material"
                [(ngModel)]="job_entry.material" >
          <option  *ngFor=" let m of materials" [ngValue]="m"> {{ 
                    m.product_name }} 
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="form-group" for="unit" >Unit</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="unit" name="unit" (onModelChange)="onUnitChange(unit)" [(ngModel)]="job_entry.units">
    <option [value]="cm">centimeters</option>
    <option [value]="inch">inches</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

class

```
 job_entry : JobEntry = <JobEntry>{};

  ngOnInit() {

this.job_entry = {
  id: null ,
   client: '',
   material: '',
   size_width: 0 ,
   size_height: 0,
   units: '',
   margin: 0,
   runs: 0,
   prints: 0,
   originals: 0,
   per_print: 0,
   discount: 0,
   price: 0
}

  onMaterialChange(material) {
  alert(material.sell_per_sqm)
  }

onUnitChange(unit) {
alert(unit)
}
```

I also get this in the console:

```
dom_renderer.ts:311 The specified value "undefined" is not a valid 
number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?
(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?
```

Anyone understand what is going on here?

Answer (score 3):

```
<option [value]="cm">centimeters</option>
<option [value]="inch">inches</option>
```

should probably be

```
<option value="cm">centimeters</option>
<option value="inch">inches</option>
```

or

```
<option [value]="'cm'">centimeters</option>
<option [value]="'inch'">inches</option>
```

otherwise Angular tries to read the `cm` and `inch` members of the components class.

Comment: Still undefined with either change. This is new `The specified value "inch" is not a valid number` , why does it need to be a number?

Comment: Are you using it somewhere where a number is required? Perhaps you can reproduce in a Plunker? I doubt this error comes from code you posted.

Comment: I added more code. The code for `material` is what I have modelled from. As this is firing my `onMaterialChange(material)` method by `alert`. I am still dumbfounded with this.

Comment: Sorry, but I still have no idea what might require the value to be a number. Is the error from the same line as the original one (`dom_renderer.ts:311`)?

Comment: got it, I used your first solution, and changed `(onModelChange)="onUnitChange(unit)"` to `ngModelChange)="onUnitChange($event)` I get my unit value now!  Human error it seems. Thanks @Günter Zöchbauer

Comment: Ok, I missed that one. Glad to hear you could make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Other alternative is:

view:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-model="unitList" ng-change="update()"
        ng-options="unit as unit.label for unit in myunits">           
</select>

<p>Selected: {{unitList.label}}</p>

</div>
```

controller:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myunits = [{
    value: 'cent',
    label: 'centimeters'
  }, {
    value: 'inch',
    label: 'inches'
  }]; 
  $scope.update = function() {
    console.log($scope.unitList.label)
  }
});
```

Check this [fiddle](https://plnkr.co/edit/4IPr0L0dUgnRPXyyqVLT?p=preview)

Comment: This looks good and I thank you for your help, but I really want to find the angular2 way of doing this, as I have never built with angularjs and want to avoid using `$scope`.